# Cannot find element from a jump out window. How can I switch to a new jump out window?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, sikuli

I'm trying to automate our system with Python2.7, Selenium-webdriver, and Sikuli. I have a problem on login. Every time I open our system, the first page is an empty page, and it will jump to another page automatically; the new page is the main login page, so Python is always trying to find the element from the first page. The first page sometimes shows:

> your session has timeout

I set a really large number for session timeout, but it doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://172.16.1.186:8080/C******E/servlet/LOGON')
# time.sleep(15)

bankid = driver.find_element_by_id("idBANK")
bankid.send_keys(01)

empid = driver.find_element_by_id("idEMPLOYEE")
empid.send_keys(200010)

pwdid = driver.fin`enter code here`d_element_by_id("idPASSWORD")
pwdid.send_keys("C******e1")

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("maint")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: Very hard to say without a url or seeing the html

Comment: The first page shows: Your Session has timed out. Please wait and you will be redirected to the LOGON screen in 5 Seconds. After 5seconds this page will be an empty page, then a new page jumps out. The URLs are totally same.This is the url: http://172.16.1.186:8080/C******E/servlet/LOGON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I can't see any Sikuli usage in your example. If you were using Sikuli, it wouldn't matter how the other page was launched as you'd be interacting with whatever is visible on your screen at that time.

In Selenium, if you have multiple windows you have to switch your driver to the correct one. A quick way to get a list of the available windows is something like this:

```
for handle in driver.window_handles:
    driver.switch_to_window(handle);
    print "Switched to handle:", handle
    element = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("title")
    print element.get_attribute("value")
```